# Convert String month to Int month [Java]

Tags: java, converters

I'm trying to convert a String month to a int month in Java. I do not want my program to have a lot of logic on it, so I'm trying to do it without having to create a switch case or a Enum. If not possible, i'll have to do deal with it and create that logic...

My String Sample is this:

```
String date = "2017-Oct-27";
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
String date = "2017-10-27";
```

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: You can use a SimpleDateFormat https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Mário Correia Do you want to use third party jar?? Also , are you using java 8??

Comment: No, I'm using java 9

Comment: @MárioCorreia Using java  8  you can do this: DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM")
                .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        TemporalAccessor accessor = parser.parse(month);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

```
String input = "2017-Oct-27";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
String formattedDate= "";
Date date;
try {
    date = parser.parse(input);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: No, it has raised an exception: Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-Oct-27"

Comment: are you passing right format, send me the logs. I have tested it locally and it works

Comment: For the translation of Oct the Locale is important; `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd", Locale.US);` (for (US) English)

Comment: hmm may be due to this he is facing issue

Comment: Yes, that was the problem Joop. I'm in Portugal, so it probably did not recognize the sintax for "out". Thanks both for your help!!!

Comment: good, i have updated my answer